# How to output all OrderLine within a period by query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thank you for reading.

I have the following table and data.

[OrderLine]
ItemID | Date | Quantity
A | 2020-06-05 | 5
B | 2020-06-05 | 5

[Item]
ItemID | ItemName
A | aItem
B | bItem
C | cItem

If I query the June 4th order quantity, no value will be displayed.
because there are no rows that satisfy 'WHERE Date = 2020-06-04'.

But I want to get the following result.

[Ordered on June 4]
ItemID | Quantity
A | 0
B | 0
C | 0

How can I get the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . You can use:

```
select p.itemid,
       nz( (select top (1) t.quantity
            from t
            where t.itemid = p.itemid and
                  t.date <= '2020-06-04'
           ), 0) as quantity
from (select distinct itemid from t) p
```